# Horizontal scrolling card not working on IOS device

Tags: html, css

I need your help please

I have creating a horizontal scrolling using HTML and CSS but not working in IOS device. Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="content ng-binding" ng-bind-html="block.content | trusted_html" sb-a-click="">
    <p>
        <a data-offline="false" data-params="value_id:193812" data-state="catalogpro-home"><strong>Dr. Aries Rutung</strong>Cardiovascular<span>March 2<sup>nd</sup> 2022</span></a>
    </p>

    <p>
        <a data-offline="true" data-params="value_id:193813" data-state="places-list"><strong>Dr. Fitria</strong>Physicologist<span>March 3<sup>th</sup> 2022</span></a>
    </p>

    <p>
        <a data-offline="false" data-params="value_id:193813" data-state="places-list-map"><strong>Dr. Jhon Doe</strong>Physicologist<span>March 6<sup>th</sup> 2022</span></a>
    </p>

    <p>
        <a data-offline="true" data-params="value_id:193813" data-state="places-categories"><strong>Dr. Maria</strong>Physicologist<span>March 9<sup>th</sup> 2022</span></a>
    </p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content.ng-binding {
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 100% !important;
    overflow-x: auto !important;
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
    white-space: nowrap !important;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important;
}

.content.ng-binding p {
    background: #3da4ff;
    background: linear-gradient(74deg, rgba(61, 164, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(76, 183, 254, 1) 100%);
    padding: 0;
    display: flex !important;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 1%;
    min-width: 58% !important;
    height: 125px;
    margin: 0 1%;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

[here is the result of the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeMcW.png)

This code working fine on Android device (using chrome and firefox) but not working when i am using IOS device (safari and chrome).

Can you guys help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: this is ionic or?

Comment: @HumbleDeveloper01 Yes, its ionic

Comment: If you have swipe remove it